# complex mutation based on difference between two dates in two different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I have two different data frames. "df1" has the registrations of diseases' incidence

```
User_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1")
User_disease <- c("a", "b", "c", "a" , "c", "d", "a", "s", "n", "b")
Diagnosis_date <- c("2020-11-23", "2020-10-12", "2020-11-25", "2020-09-30", "2020-12-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-10-28", "2020-12-09", "2020-06-24", "2020-08-15")
df1 <- data.frame(User_ID, User_disease, Diagnosis_date)
```

and the second "df2" has records of hospital visits for the same patients

```
User_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "2", "1", "4", "3", "5")
Visit_date <- c("2020-09-23", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-14", "2020-09-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-24", "2020-12-07", "2020-06-13", "2020-08-12","2020-06-23", "2020-07-11", "2020-12-25", "2020-05-30", "2020-11-29", "2020-12-10", "2020-10-25", "2020-12-21", "2020-09-24", "2020-11-15")
df2 <- data.frame(User_ID, Visit_date)
```

I want to add to "df1" a new column to indicate whether a patient has any hospital visit within 30 days prior to Diagnosis date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. First I added an event ID column to df1. Then used inner join to create a new data frame df3 before I created a lubridate time interval to check whether a patient visited the hospital within 30 days prior to diagnosis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

User_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1")
User_disease <- c("a", "b", "c", "a" , "c", "d", "a", "s", "n", "b")
Event_ID <- 1:10
Diagnosis_date <- c("2020-11-23", "2020-10-12", "2020-11-25", "2020-09-30", "2020-12-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-10-28", "2020-12-09", "2020-06-24", "2020-08-15")
df1 <- data.frame(User_ID, User_disease, Event_ID, Diagnosis_date) %>%
  mutate(Diagnosis_date = ymd(Diagnosis_date))

User_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "2", "1", "4", "3", "5")
Visit_date <- c("2020-09-23", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-14", "2020-09-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-24", "2020-12-07", "2020-06-13", "2020-08-12","2020-06-23", "2020-07-11", "2020-12-25", "2020-05-30", "2020-11-29", "2020-12-10", "2020-10-25", "2020-12-21", "2020-09-24", "2020-11-15")
df2 <- data.frame(User_ID, Visit_date) %>%
  mutate(Visit_date = ymd(Visit_date))

df3 <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by = "User_ID") %>%
  mutate(fdate30 = ymd(Visit_date) + days(30)) %>%
  mutate(ed_interval = interval(Visit_date, fdate30)) %>% 
  mutate(ed4w = Diagnosis_date %within% ed_interval) %>%
  filter(ed4w == "TRUE")

df1$ed4w <- df3$ed4w[match(df1$Event_ID, df3$Event_ID)]

df1$ed4w[is.na(df1$ed4w)] <- "FALSE"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `lubridate` duration with some filtering of the visit data frame should do the trick:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

User_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1")
User_disease <- c("a", "b", "c", "a" , "c", "d", "a", "s", "n", "b")
Diagnosis_date <- c("2020-11-23", "2020-10-12", "2020-11-25", "2020-09-30", "2020-12-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-10-28", "2020-12-09", "2020-06-24", "2020-08-15")
df1 <- data.frame(User_ID, User_disease, Diagnosis_date) %>%
  mutate(Diagnosis_date = ymd(Diagnosis_date))

User_ID_Visit <- c("1", "2", "3", "4","2", "5", "6","1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "2", "1", "4", "3", "5")
Visit_date <- c("2020-09-23", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-14", "2020-09-23", "2020-12-12", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-24", "2020-12-07", "2020-06-13", "2020-08-12","2020-06-23", "2020-07-11", "2020-12-25", "2020-05-30", "2020-11-29", "2020-12-10", "2020-10-25", "2020-12-21", "2020-09-24", "2020-11-15")
df2 <- data.frame(User_ID_Visit, Visit_date) %>%
  mutate(Visit_date = ymd(Visit_date))

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(visited_last_month = any(between(filter(df2, User_ID_Visit == User_ID)$Visit_date %--% Diagnosis_date / ddays(1), 0, 30))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#    User_ID User_disease Diagnosis_date visited_last_month
#    <chr>   <chr>        <date>         <lgl>             
#  1 1       a            2020-11-23     TRUE              
#  2 2       b            2020-10-12     TRUE              
#  3 3       c            2020-11-25     TRUE              
#  4 4       a            2020-09-30     TRUE              
#  5 2       c            2020-12-23     TRUE              
#  6 5       d            2020-12-12     TRUE              
#  7 6       a            2020-10-28     FALSE             
#  8 1       s            2020-12-09     TRUE              
#  9 4       n            2020-06-24     TRUE              
# 10 1       b            2020-08-15     TRUE
```

Please notice that I made some changes to you input data.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved the issue. Have a question, will we get FALSE for cases in df1 that are not in df2? (patient diagnosed with one of the disease but never had a hospital)visit).

Comment: Does abs() here mean that we including those who visited the hospital within a month before or after diagnosis?

Comment: No, `abs()` means we take the absolute value of a series of day differences (numbers). Feel free to read the documentation of these functions, and to play with them yourself.

Comment: I think with abs() we are assessing whether patients visited the hospital within a duration of 30 days before or after diagnosis. if you add a date that for patient 6 (currently FALSE) for a visit within that happen in a week after diagnosis, say the visited on 9/11/2020 we will get a TRUE. I tried to the code without abs() but getting "coercing argument of type 'double' to logical" warning. Need only those who visited the hospital before diagnosis. Sorry but would appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I fixed it. Try playing with the between values of 0 and 30 if I misunderstood again. Let me know if this works.